# Warning:"pointless comparison of unsigned integer with zero" cuda

Tags: c++, cuda, warnings, unsigned-integer

On doing

```
if(blockIdx.y-threadIdx.y >=0){
//some operation }
```

I get the above warning. Can anyone tell me why the CUDA compiler throws this as a warning. I am just trying to allow only those threads which meet the above criteria into the if statement.
And if I ignore it , will it have any consequences?
Note that i am launching multiple blocks as:

```
dim3 nblocks (7,7)
dim3 nthreadsperblock (256,256)
kernel<<<nblocks,nthreadsperblock>>>(...)
```

Comment: Warning tells you everything. You substract two **unsigned** values so the result will be always at least 0

Comment: @mpiatek for blockidx.y =1 , threads with threadix.y >1 will result in negative value right? I am trying to filter that out

Comment: @darkfall94: No. The result of an unsigned expression has unsigned type and thus is necessarily non-negative. unsigned types behave as modular arithmetic on the integers mod TYPE_MAX+1.

Comment: @darkfall94 R answered you, just wanted to add it's defined in C++ standard - 4.7 Integral conversions [conv.integral]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should cast the variables to `signed int`s or change the expression to `if(blockIdx.y>=threadIdx.y){` which is mathematical identical to `if(blockIdx.y-threadIdx.y >=0){`.

Shortly you can replace all `(a - b *op* 0)` to `(a *op* b)` where `*op*` is one of the comparison-operators.

Comment: Casting is not equivalent and not safe here without further assumptions on the range of possible values . You have to rewrite the expression as in your second solution.